# Returning a valid JSON object which is to be handled by JS promise

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, axios, webapp2

My intention is to return a list of entities in JSON format which is then handled by the client-side JS using Promises.

I am returning a JSON object like this:

```
from webapp2_extras import json

class AllPostsJson(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        posts = Post.query().fetch()
        self.response.content_type = 'application/json'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        self.response.out.write(json.encode([p.to_dict() for p in posts]))
```

Then I am using the axios library to make the request:

```
posts = axios.get('example.com/posts-json').then(resp => resp.data)
console.log(posts) // output: Promise {<pending>}
```

I had expected the `posts` variable to contain an array of Post objects, but it outputs this to the console instead:

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: 
Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but you may be setting your header incorrectly.  This is how I set my headers for JSON:

```
self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: It's related with [this paragraph](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/request-response-headers#content-type).